# Vernünftiges sein wollen?

Tags: meaning

I am striving with translating an old philosophy text:

*Nur der Vernünftige kann somit vernünftig und Vernünftiges sein wollen.*

How would you rephrase the last "**Vernünftiges**" (sein wollen) in modern German and/or translate it to English?

Comment: Hat dieser Text auch einen Autor und einen Titel, den man nennen könnte, sowie Seitenzahlen?

Answer (score 4):

A bit more of a context may help, but this fits quite well:

> And so, only the reasonable can be reasonable and be wanting to be something reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

> Thus only the reasonable one might strive for reasonability, be it either in kind or existence.

The author is referring to being comprised by reasonability as a whole, as opposed to merely wielding it as a tool of leisure.